# Aurora postgres taking high CPU in type query and that query is not executed by our app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-aurora

We have integrated our application with Aurora Postgres 9.6.
Our application in rails and we use https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool to connect Aurora cluster

I was reviewing query in performance-insights and I see one query take huge CPU and that query was not executed by us and we do not have any pg type query from the app.

```
SELECT oid, typname, typelem, typdelim, typinput FROM pg_type
```

can you Please help us to understand why this query is executed and who execute this query and why it taking high CPU.
how we can resolve this.

Comment: This should be fast. Maybe it is executed too often? Install `pg_stat_statements` and see what your top time consuming queries are. I don't know what could issue such a statement; it somehow looks like a metadata query run by an ORM or application development framework.

Comment: This is on RDS so i cannot install any additional plugin

Comment: If you can configure the log file, use pgBadger for the same purpose.

Comment: as @LaurenzAlbe already mentioned, use pg_stat_statements, additionally you can install a tool like pghero for a graphical analysis and enhancements in your database.